# Как символизировать краш логи?

Tags: ios, swift

Я пытаюсь символизировать логи от ревьювера Apple разными способами. Но мой краш файл не полностью символизируется. Я пробовал следующие способы:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45207863
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53496185
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30431450

Но во всех способах у меня один и тот же результат:
Что я делаю не так?

```
{"app_name":"Таблетка","timestamp":"2020-04-23 01:58:35.00 -0700","app_version":"1.1.1","slice_uuid":"c6b79bc-f4ab-38af-a03c-97a7b236ce09","adam_id":150323218,"build_version":"1.1.1","bundleID":"ARКP","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.4.1 (17E262)","incident_id":"23E9AC9-62CF-427-A553-A1714900924","name":"Таблетка"}
Incident Identifier: 23E98AC9-62CF-427-A553-A17149080924
CrashReporter Key:   7e03d2b9035b4c2316e0cf3851701e3c06f270f
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Таблетка [482]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/17241A1-06DA-43E2-A7C3-9DC83DD2655A/Таблетка.app/Таблетка
Identifier:          ARКP
Version:             1.1.1 (1.1.1)
AppStoreTools:       11E503a
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           ARКP [553]


Date/Time:           2020-04-23 01:58:35.4385 -0700
Launch Time:         2020-04-23 01:58:32.6319 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.4.1 (17E262)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010422d048
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [482]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Таблетка                        0x000000010422d048 0x10420c000 + 135240
1   Таблетка                        0x000000010422d0b0 0x10420c000 + 135344
2   UIKitCore                       0x0000000185b38e08 -[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 100
3   UIKitCore                       0x0000000185b3d898 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 936
4   UIKitCore                       0x0000000185b3dca0 -[UIViewController view] + 28
5   UIKitCore                       0x0000000185a68ccc -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 80
6   UIKitCore                       0x0000000185a5c810 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 188
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000185b4d4bc -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 2616
8   UIKitCore                       0x0000000185b50014 __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 104
9   UIKitCore                       0x0000000185b5051c -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 508
10  UIKitCore                       0x0000000185b4ff64 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 196
11  UIKitCore                       0x0000000185b501d0 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 164
12  UIKitCore                       0x00000001862dddb0 __67-[UIStoryboardModalSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 248
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001862e2ac4 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 292
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001862e2970 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 92
15  UIKitCore                       0x0000000185b403b0 -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 104
16  Таблетка                        0x000000010421ba30 0x10420c000 + 64048
17  Таблетка                        0x000000010421b124 0x10420c000 + 61732
18  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186357b4c -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:isCellMultiSelect:] + 1200
19  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186357684 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 108
20  UIKitCore                       0x0000000186357e8c -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 268
21  UIKitCore                       0x000000018618794c _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 316
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001861772f4 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 232
23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001861a7744 _afterCACommitHandler + 76
24  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182050fb8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
25  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018204beac __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 420
26  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018204c328 __CFRunLoopRun + 968
27  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018204bc34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
28  GraphicsServices                0x000000018c19538c GSEventRunModal + 160
29  UIKitCore                       0x000000018617e22c UIApplicationMain + 1932
30  Таблетка                        0x00000001042131d8 0x10420c000 + 29144
31  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000181ed3800 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181ded738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181ded738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.runningboardservices.background-workloop
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ea7198 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ea660c mach_msg + 72
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181d54c04 _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply + 560
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181d54fcc dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply$VARIANT$mp + 52
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000181c9a9d8 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 236
5   RunningBoardServices            0x0000000184c48ba8 -[RBSXPCMessage sendToConnection:error:] + 412
6   RunningBoardServices            0x0000000184c492dc -[RBSXPCMessage invokeOnConnection:withReturnCollectionClass:entryClass:error:] + 100
7   RunningBoardServices            0x0000000184c310bc -[RBSConnection acquireAssertion:error:] + 424
8   RunningBoardServices            0x0000000184c2dda4 -[RBSAssertion acquireWithError:] + 204
9   AssertionServices               0x00000001868685fc -[BKSAssertion acquire] + 180
10  AssertionServices               0x000000018686d0b0 -[BKSProcessAssertion acquire] + 680
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181d989a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181d99524 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181d474a4 _dispatch_workloop_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 1920
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181d4f78c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181deab74 _pthread_wqthread + 272
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181ded740 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181ded738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181ded738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ea7198 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181ea660c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001820513b4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 148
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018204c3e8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1160
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018204bc34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   Foundation                      0x000000018238ebcc -[NSRunLoop+ 31692 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228
6   Foundation                      0x000000018238eaac -[NSRunLoop+ 31404 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000186220160 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 152
8   Foundation                      0x00000001824bd9d0 __NSThread__start__ + 848
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181de9d98 _pthread_start + 156
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181ded74c thread_start + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181ded738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0xfe6af37e971c097e   x1: 0x0000000000000004   x2: 0x0000000000000024   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000039   x7: 0x0000000000000c40
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0xee6db4f7385f00e7  x10: 0x0000000000000001  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000280740b00  x13: 0x000001a1cd022979  x14: 0x0000000000000006  x15: 0x00000001c17e81a8
   x16: 0x0000000181e10a90  x17: 0x0000000181fbbb78  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0xe300000000000000  x23: 0x0000000104269000
   x24: 0x0000000000525545  x25: 0xe600000000000000  x26: 0xe500000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000010426e8a0   fp: 0x000000016bbf1e20   lr: 0x000000010422ca5c
    sp: 0x000000016bbf1ce0   pc: 0x000000010422d048 cpsr: 0x60000000
   esr: 0xf2000001  Address size fault

Binary Images:
0x10420c000 - 0x10425ffff Таблетка arm64  <cb6b79bcf4ab38afa03c97a7b236ce09> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/173241A1-06DA-43E2-A7C3-9DC83DD2655A/Таблетка.app/Таблетка
0x104578000 - 0x104583fff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64  <2df134bae62230edb227eb9333bfa4d9> /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
0x104664000 - 0x1046c7fff dyld arm64  <23eead922ec9376cbb08574507ab6177> /usr/lib/dyld
0x181c78000 - 0x181c8efff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <f67d8aff28893f9abf166036c3203325> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x181c8f000 - 0x181cc0fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <9e9d069de3b136fa85755e1d9e6b6b54> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x181cc1000 - 0x181cc1fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <0afa438b8355370794f5015ad81f32df> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x181cc2000 - 0x181d3dfff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <8d39ff48e14c3f868e1090f54896bb65> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x181d3e000 - 0x181db2fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <5a83d0cf8fb937278a32012d20a47ec8> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x181db3000 - 0x181dd3fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <a0a7d67af0f3399a8f006f92716d8e6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x181dd4000 - 0x181ddefff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <a5d5822c76223859b0c0b869b7e244b5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x181ddf000 - 0x181deffff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <fb1dd49f0cfb3114bdb40ef7be44f6bc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x181df0000 - 0x181e21fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <091241f8e94c39ba9ca67352e998bb41> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x181e22000 - 0x181e89fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <28c07c08a95635b1b04e88d84542020b> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x181e8a000 - 0x181ea2fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <f07199ac8a903127b17f0a906ffb7302> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x181ea3000 - 0x181ed1fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <b422ba38a9f63062be28d28d39e3fe25> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x181ed2000 - 0x181f04fff libdyld.dylib arm64  <876fb49abfba37bfad376ffc90f7f981> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x181f05000 - 0x181f0dfff libsystem_darwin.dylib arm64  <fc50d2ff80ac31179ff0608fa6cff3a3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
0x181f0e000 - 0x181f67fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <d7934e7f3eed3c078d1342fe55250c88> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x181f68000 - 0x181fa8fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <6a94223de5dc3df6b89780ba56191d92> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x181fa9000 - 0x18231cfff CoreFoundation arm64  <409609cd841038e1ba5dbded609d2018> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x18231d000 - 0x182386fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <b1f843cc55883c0ba02fc5b80883cc9c> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x182387000 - 0x18263efff Foundation arm64  <1a46239df2fc34b695bc9f38869f0c85> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x18263f000 - 0x182671fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <b5116ed3cf69347d85687d2c8d5d76c0> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x182672000 - 0x1827ecfff CoreServices arm64  <43035d98ba1c3d5d972fd61df826fcb3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices
0x1827ed000 - 0x18284dfff libSparse.dylib arm64  <fd83188d02163838a7c012b81f36e440> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparse.dylib
0x18284e000 - 0x182d38fff ImageIO arm64  <428fc36a6d0234b5a10cc2cf6f9e0674> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x182d39000 - 0x182d3bfff ConstantClasses arm64  <07aead6b70b73890b27f7aea1cd02350> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x182d3c000 - 0x182edafff CoreText arm64  <3a068b6f533e36b18e9823833c815854> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x182edb000 - 0x183010fff Security arm64  <d5a88c36cb0932a6906055bbc4b6817d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x183011000 - 0x1830b4fff IOKit arm64  <d138895882be3a12964aa53ca8da1b74> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x1830b5000 - 0x1830ecfff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <fe7d38beb09530eca24b70bc964ec273> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x1830ed000 - 0x183149fff libprotobuf.dylib arm64  <027d49d7fea839cda49a4a4fb32c7f6f> /usr/lib/libprotobuf.dylib
0x18314a000 - 0x18315bfff libprotobuf-lite.dylib arm64  <2c82919a66fa30a7841320190f2c202d> /usr/lib/libprotobuf-lite.dylib
0x18315c000 - 0x1833acfff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <e00735d86bab31f8acbac8fdb01f290e> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x1833d7000 - 0x18341efff WirelessDiagnostics arm64  <dc60c14089ab3ecb916e94fb63a2ae46> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/WirelessDiagnostics
0x18341f000 - 0x183458fff libAWDSupport.dylib arm64  <52926ffdcfd0397881e93a4df6893672> /usr/lib/libAWDSupport.dylib
0x183459000 - 0x1838ddfff CoreAudio arm64  <e467570caf523683bf36ce2594f1c98e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x1838de000 - 0x183baafff CoreImage arm64  <4aee50c9e546312ead5d721a6afdb059> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x183bab000 - 0x183c99fff LanguageModeling arm64  <1d022988ea363113a096c2f107568542> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x183c9a000 - 0x183ce0fff Lexicon arm64  <9d08273daeac34e78493ff7bff76cab2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Lexicon.framework/Lexicon
0x183ce1000 - 0x183e63fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <4fadb9ee56a73afca3604780ddf3411b> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x183e64000 - 0x183e96fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <6cf66de926bb32089688747ed1dbd888> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x183e97000 - 0x183ea0fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <21a918766a2c3f89855046e0f854018a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x183ea1000 - 0x184082fff CoreDuet arm64  <5640bda664273303800ed189c16e8049> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuet.framework/CoreDuet
0x184083000 - 0x1841c5fff Montreal arm64  <69a3d186833f35c5963a43e4d365e897> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Montreal.framework/Montreal
0x1841c6000 - 0x1842acfff NLP arm64  <22401c0f186737c295999afaf82b1840> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NLP.framework/NLP
0x1842ad000 - 0x1842cafff CellularPlanManager arm64  <c88939c958243367b5401c11b803b8d1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CellularPlanManager.framework/CellularPlanManager
0x1842cb000 - 0x184308fff AppSupport arm64  <1731e2fba0303bdbb0cf8b02e5e56ecd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x184309000 - 0x1847dafff libnetwork.dylib arm64  <cf9b76bf435b38d2aed3fb2c050d9216> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
0x1847db000 - 0x1848e7fff ManagedConfiguration arm64  <a40f654260d932528c5ebff3f5575cab> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x1848e8000 - 0x184911fff CoreServicesStore arm64  <c16b4fad3e753a2e85d67639481e8080> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesStore.framework/CoreServicesStore
0x184912000 - 0x184932fff UserManagement arm64  <ad5afd364e75332288e4a3bbcce41b5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserManagement.framework/UserManagement
0x184933000 - 0x184beafff CoreML arm64  <4b1ed9735bef37929aa9775df017a4f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreML.framework/CoreML
0x184beb000 - 0x184c01fff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <4e652067e296363bbfa380eba32585ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x184c02000 - 0x184c1cfff CommonUtilities arm64  <8c65f3b91e6d322ebeedf8a0e60e717a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x184c1d000 - 0x184c1dfff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <b9fc54b519c53301bda0c5607f0e7806> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x184c1e000 - 0x184c54fff RunningBoardServices arm64  <c78723a9f231370b8944596226f2b836> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RunningBoardServices.framework/RunningBoardServices
0x184c55000 - 0x184cd2fff BaseBoard arm64  <33a252545a9730ab9cc7fad0345d4758> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x184cd3000 - 0x185228fff SiriTTS arm64  <f4cc905a59803fe5b6283c8d3b2e70c7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SiriTTS.framework/SiriTTS
0x185229000 - 0x18529bfff CoreLocation arm64  <c8b1e677d38435d38b12bab96c65a426> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x1852a9000 - 0x1852fdfff Accounts arm64  <75940abf4f773731855da69467dbb796> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x18530f000 - 0x185671fff CFNetwork arm64  <c4865497192b3dbe81e984a99b788adf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x185672000 - 0x185751fff UIFoundation arm64  <5633754447e039efbb34f207fda2553c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x185752000 - 0x186866fff UIKitCore arm64  <3062ff32218237a2a5f9b38f6fb6b8c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x186867000 - 0x186874fff AssertionServices arm64  <eff14a5c8feb33c1ac3004921caa2a25> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x186875000 - 0x186947fff CoreTelephony arm64  <f04a58a0c439319784c1f4ea154f6363> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x186948000 - 0x18694dfff AggregateDictionary arm64  <e0ce74236eb13c98bb05186b7f4e3d2b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x18694e000 - 0x186964fff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <24190e9ac7db3006b4dfc5e64e85774a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x186965000 - 0x1869ddfff CloudDocs arm64  <c2f43b62730b3b8ba93d6acca741d864> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudDocs.framework/CloudDocs
0x1869de000 - 0x186d06fff CoreData arm64  <a654d396b79c3f469e3fbe9ec0ee1af4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x186d07000 - 0x186f2cfff Vision arm64  <958d82a44f733f0f96350b6f68bd9381> /System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision
0x186f2d000 - 0x186f6ffff PhotoFoundation arm64  <9e49f30ca736349893a9716346e41898> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoFoundation.framework/PhotoFoundation
0x186f70000 - 0x186f9bfff BoardServices arm64  <728b59e6907e31e5892de5b2c55c48ce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BoardServices.framework/BoardServices
0x187052000 - 0x187060fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <3a3722da76863c2a99c2cce0e3924bf7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x187061000 - 0x187081fff CoreAnalytics arm64  <85843ee0a89b3316a3e68531eba75336> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAnalytics.framework/CoreAnalytics
0x187082000 - 0x1871f2fff CloudKit arm64  <d54d14692ec130d7b5af5f852438dc3e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit
0x1871f3000 - 0x187240fff SpringBoardServices arm64  <50878840805636d7bff4a6aa6d6cdfa9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x187241000 - 0x1872b3fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <ca8e712fa22732ae842b65567f6046bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x1872b4000 - 0x1873dbfff Network arm64  <38a032852b86333e95c553eb41e5d3e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Network.framework/Network
0x187439000 - 0x187440fff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <a0e89bc6db7f3c578468bdc9ae67fdcb> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x187441000 - 0x18832bfff GeoServices arm64  <d2fc5b30d98a352d952013a5b60a073b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x18832c000 - 0x188334fff TCC arm64  <e8eb1bfdf24d34f2a53b5d0700632050> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x188335000 - 0x18838efff IMFoundation arm64  <b2d85b147b823944beebc644d365b564> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x18838f000 - 0x188502fff CoreUtils arm64  <b642c3a48cdc3b1aba6d651b7e00d61c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/CoreUtils
0x1885b5000 - 0x1885eafff ImageCaptureCore arm64  <99700767f48d36cb8ccb1d9e33962eda> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageCaptureCore.framework/ImageCaptureCore
0x1885eb000 - 0x1885f4fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <4764ee5a2f0a3fbb8a756f60f0e02cd8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x1885f5000 - 0x188670fff AppleAccount arm64  <972cea5083b43105b83f737be8ad7a43> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x188671000 - 0x18868bfff ApplePushService arm64  <89033f36d91031a594a517ecea968a3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x18868c000 - 0x188774fff IDS arm64  <cf2b018761f736d4a1dfad15aa703c85> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/IDS
0x188775000 - 0x18889ffff IDSFoundation arm64  <a6bd395156ff3624b78997bb3ed24a06> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDSFoundation.framework/IDSFoundation
0x1888a0000 - 0x1888a1fff libCTGreenTeaLogger.dylib arm64  <2ab5f36320803bda84913992c492743e> /usr/lib/libCTGreenTeaLogger.dylib
0x188906000 - 0x188a06fff CoreMedia arm64  <b9bf44cd041a37af8879451f66687468> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x188a07000 - 0x188a16fff UIKitServices arm64  <0eeb42c795483dba82a142eeda85503e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitServices.framework/UIKitServices
0x188a17000 - 0x188a74fff BackBoardServices arm64  <6f0540d2fedc308eacff631bff19cd69> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x188a75000 - 0x188cc6fff QuartzCore arm64  <ba9eccee9f613baab8a88eb3b7e0a24f> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x188cc7000 - 0x188d8efff ColorSync arm64  <503c108270703f1786df14588e7f9ff7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ColorSync.framework/ColorSync
0x188d8f000 - 0x1892fefff CoreGraphics arm64  <e068b7652d603d90aba30df6da3578bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x1892ff000 - 0x18942efff Contacts arm64  <18807e6ef924349a9384161c92390665> /System/Library/Frameworks/Contacts.framework/Contacts
0x18942f000 - 0x18945dfff UserNotifications arm64  <44b07041e9723af2a6446a04bc8588a7> /System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/UserNotifications
0x18945e000 - 0x189481fff LocationSupport arm64  <470b39d55daf3170b1a38841292d494d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LocationSupport.framework/LocationSupport
0x189482000 - 0x1895ddfff Sharing arm64  <34759ac26e85385f9cca89d83469028d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Sharing.framework/Sharing
0x1895de000 - 0x189c1dfff WebKit arm64  <0d71fc8cc7e331948094d1c767c7bc09> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x189c1e000 - 0x18b9d2fff WebCore arm64  <fbf9a3b9df503629af395c41d3e4e83a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x18b9d3000 - 0x18b9edfff libAccessibility.dylib arm64  <f55983edebf933948322efaefe1ecbca> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x18b9ee000 - 0x18b9f9fff AXCoreUtilities arm64  <c9ced073466a32208dbabf96d0a50f15>
```

etc...

Я так понимаю, что символизировано все кроме самых нужных строк с названием приложения? Вообще как-то можно понять где происходит ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я в свое время сделал для себя такую памятку, когда больше ничего не помогало

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Last Exception Backtrace:

*Cм. мануалы по утилите `atos`, суть в подготовке списка адресов для этой утилиты, запускаем из директории, куда предварительно помещен бинарник приложения, взятый из dSYM*

```
MyApp                  0x1001441dc 0x1000f0000 + 344540

atos -arch arm64 -o MyApp -l 0x1000f0000 0x1001441dc
```

> Using the -f  argument to specify the path of an
>   input file containing white-space-separated numeric addresses

Берем перечень адресов, как показано выше и генерим список для `atos` с помощью регулярных выражений в три этапа например в Sublime Text, можно и вручную при желании

```
1.
^([\d]+[\s]+[\w\.+]+[\s]+)

2.
[+]\s[\d]+\n

3.
find:
^([0x].*) ([0x].*) $
replace:
${2} ${1}
```

**Дополнение**

Согласно секции "Symbolicating Crash Reports With atos" из документа по ссылке нужно взять бинарник из файла `dSYM`, а не из `app`

> Locate the dSYM file for the binary. You can use Spotlight to find the
>   matching dSYM file for the UUID of the binary image. See the
>   Symbolication Troubleshooting section. dSYM files are bundles in which
>   reside a file containing the DWARF debugging information generated by
>   the compiler at build time. You must provide the path to this file,
>   not to the dSYM bundle, when invoking atos.
>
> ```
> With the above information you can symbolicate addresses in the backtrace using the atos command. You can specify multiple addresses
> ```
>
> to symbolicate, separated by a space.
>
> ```
> atos -arch <Binary Architecture> -o <Path to dSYM file>/Contents/Resources/DWARF/<binary image name> -l <load address>
> ```
>
> Listing 1  Example usage of the atos command following the steps
>   above, and the resulting output.

```
$ atos -arch arm64 -o
TheElements.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/TheElements -l
0x1000e4000 0x00000001000effdc
```

> -[AtomicElementViewController myTransitionDidStop:finished:context:]

Comment: Спасибо! Но вот какая проблема. Я запускаю терминал и ввожу следующую команду `atos -arch arm64 -o Таблетка -l 0x10420c000 0x000000010422d0b0` и получаю `atos cannot load symbols for the file Таблетка for architecture arm64`

Comment: Как я понимаю, мне нужно символизировать 0,1,16,17 строки. Из них станет ясно в чем дело? Я пробовал пробить адреса через https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/crashfinder/id1242770247?mt=12 но тоже ничего не находит

Comment: @111 см дополнение

Comment: Вот что получил расшифровав 0 строку - `InfoViewController.viewDidLoad() (in –Ґ–∞–±–ї–µ—В–Ї–∞) (InfoViewController.swift:113)` Значит вылетает на 113 строке?

Comment: @111 да, и кракозябры вместо названия проги так как она у вас на кириллице